# Hashset delete old instances

Tags: c#, date, hashset

I have a hashset of my custom class that I serialize and deserialize, how can I delete old instances of classes that are older than say 1 day?

Comment: Do you have any serialization timestamp or any property in the custom class that can be used to identify the date of creation.

Comment: During the deserialization it should throw an exception if it can't properly deserialize. Couldn't you wrap it in a try catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HashSet.RemoveWhere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361254.aspx):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
hashSet1.RemoveWhere(obj => (now - obj.DateTimeProperty).TotalDays >= 1);
```

(assuming `DateTimeProperty` is a  `DateTime` property in your class)

> Is there a way I can loop through all the deleted objects before I
>   remove them?

@user2372936: Then i would filter the objects that you'll delete first, loop them and use [`HashSet.Remove(obj)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342694.aspx) to delete them:

```
var toDelete = hashSet1.Where(obj => (now - obj.DateTimeProperty).TotalDays >= 1);
foreach(var obj in toDelete){
    //...;
    hashSet1.Remove(obj);
}
```

Comment: That's cool! Is there a way I can loop through all the deleted objects before I remove them?

Comment: @user2372936: Then i would filter the objects that you'll delete first, loop them and use [`HashSet.Remove(obj)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342694.aspx) to delete them: `var toDelete = hashSet1.Where(sameConditionAsAbove);foreach(var obj in toDelete){//...;hashSet1.Remove(obj);}`. Edited my answer accordingly.